# How to enable double-click

Tags: applications

Is it possible to do double-click on Android like you do on a regular computer? Some websites require double-click to operate, and I was hoping I could do the same on Android and get a computer double-click behavior instead of Android double tap zoom.

Comment: What websites are you using that require double clicking? I can't think of any at all that use that (except if you want to select text, which is more of a browser/OS thing than it is a website design). There are plenty that use `hover` actions which can be problematic.

Comment: its a trading website on steam platform. screenshot here [link](http://puu.sh/7DMNv.png) To push items from my inventory to trade i need to double click or drag them

Comment: Somewhat, a good question. Anyway, website for testing double-click: http://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html, since I couldn't do it even on the latest Chrome on Lollipop 5.1.

Comment: Related [Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 doesn't recognize double-clicks](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59367/galaxy-tab-3-10-1-doesnt-recognize-double-clicks)..Not all website are meant for mobile and not all website work in all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Just created this account just to share this priceless information... Try and instal "[**Puffin browser**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree&hl=en)" on googleplay.. It has the virtual mouse that works like a charm! Thank me later and the developer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) with the plugin [NoDoubleTap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/addon/nodoubletap/) that lets you disable double tap zooming.

Hopefully that will let Android pass both taps through to the website so it can register a double click.

Comment: i tried it. it doesn't work

Comment: NoDoubleTap addon is gone: "[If you’ve followed a link from another site for an extension or theme, that item is no longer available.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/addon/nodoubletap/)"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only browser I've found that works is Puffin.  I have to use the virtual mouse and a BT mouse together but it does work.

Comment: I should clarify the two mice.  I have to place the virtual mouse on what I want to double tap and then I have to use the bt mouse to actually double click it.  It might just be a bug in my work's webpage but it works for me.